# How to extract the first element of a list in XQuery 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I want to extract the first element form the list `$res/Name`. In my solution I obtain all the list and not only the first element, here is what I wrote.

```
for $res in /Restaurants/Restaurant
let $n := count($res/Dish)
order by $n descending
return ($res/Name)[1]
```

You can see here the XML and the result: http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/7992b12910492f493273835e828dc386

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The positional filter is part of the return clause expression, so you get the first `Name` for each `$res`.

However you want it to apply to the complete result. Moving the parentheses should solve that:

```
(
  for $res in /Restaurants/Restaurant
  let $n := count($res/Dish)
  order by $n descending
  return $res/Name
)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use XQuery 3.0, it knows the helper functions `fn:head($sequence)` and `fn:tail($sequence)`.

Example:

```
head(1 to 10)
1
tail(1 to 10)
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot use XQuery 3.0 BTW if I had used fn:head I could have written:  `for $res in /Restaurants/Restaurant
let $n := count($res/Dish)
order by $n descending
return head($res/Name)`

Comment: No, you would have wrapped the `head(...)` around the whole statement, similar to the predicate. In the end, `head` and `tail` are just syntactical sugar for the positional predicates `[1]` and `[position() ne 1]`, but can help writing code that's easier to read.